# Swift Optionals - Inconsistency?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm slightly confused - I thought I understood Optionals and on the Apple dev forums Chris L, mentioned a work around to the immutable Optional issue was to create a class wrapper for the optional value type. -[link](https://devforums.apple.com/message/998882#998882%20%20(I%20thought%20implying%20that%20class/reference%20type%20optionals%20properties%20are%20mutable)!

However take this example with UIWindow (an optional class type with various properties)

The properties still don't seem mutable with optional chaining!

```
var window: UIWindow?

//this works (force unwrap)
self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()


//this optional chain doesn't work... why not? Isn't this just a safer version of the above?
self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

**This seems to be fixed in beta 5!**

Comment: the optional chaining is working on the _right_ side of the operand only, you cannot chain optionally an object and tell its property must be _this_. it would be like setting a possible `nil` pointer equal with some other value – which is invalid operand, **not inconsistency**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## update for Xcode beta 5

---

the originally asked issue has been resolved in Xcode beta5, that may invalidate this answer.

---

## original anwer

---

that may request further explanation, why it is definitely *not inconsistent* behaviour but is simple invalid.

#### the optional *value* has to be always of the *right* side of the actual operand, and it cannot be on the *left* side of it.

see that logic via two simple examples:

### example 1

in case of this line of code:

```
self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
                      < LEFT ^ RIGHT >
```

the optional is on the *left* side which would mean the *left* side could be `nil` therefore the following operand would appear here in runtime:

```
nil = UIColor.redColor()
```

which is clearly invalid on every level without any further or complex explanation – a `nil` cannot be assigned to something else, that is why the compiler does not allow it.

> **NOTE:** you may assume that the logical behaviour would be like this in the case of `self.window = nil`:
>
> ```
> nil.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
> ```
>
> but the documentation about [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) highlights a very important behaviour which explains why that is not happening at all:
>
> > Multiple queries can be chained together, and the **entire** chain fails gracefully if any link in the chain is `nil`.

emphasis is on the word *"entire"*, thus that is why the *left* side will be `nil = ...` and **not** `nil.backgroundColor = ...` as you'd expect after *Objective-C*.

### example 2

the other answer highligths another idea of how it can be solved:

```
self.window?.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.redColor())
```

why is that working? would it not be a little inconsistency here? definitely not.

the actual optional is on the *right* side of the operand here, because that line is equal to this line, however we are not bothered to get the `void` in practice at all.

```
let result: Void! = self.window?.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.redColor())
           < LEFT ^ RIGHT >
```

as you see there is not any inconsistency at all here, because in the case of `self.window = nil` that line would be equal to this one in runtime <sup>*(please see the explanation above)*</sup>:

```
let result: Void! = nil
```

and that would be a completely legal operand.

#### the logic is simple, the optional must be always at the *right* side of the operand (or operator), on the *left* side it can be non-optional *value* only.

Comment: Thank you for the above. Very interesting read - I think I had a fundamental misunderstanding of the problem. Either way, if what you say is true (which I believe it is) there is not going to be any change to this behavior... Which means myArray?.removeAtIndex(0) (as per the conversation on Apple Dev Forums) will never be valid Swift right?

Comment: the `myArray?.removeAtIndex(0)` is a 3rd case currently, because the `-removeAtIndex(_:)` is a `mutating` method, and they can be invoked on a mutable instance only. in fact it seems the optional objects are immutable instances in _Xcode beta3_ and I feel that'd be a kind of bug here. nothing indicates (logically!) why the optional _must be_ immutable instances in one too. you may ask a question about it, the community may have idea about that, but my personal view is that I feel it as a glitch or bug right now – but I make mistakes too. :)

Comment: @JohnWoods, one more thought about the topic you've asked, there is a very less information about how `mutating` methods work in background, so we may not now something which can determine the straight answer to your question.

Comment: just thinking and rereading your answer, even if optionals are made mutable in future betas, we still will not be able to assign an non unwrapped optional right? Only when unwrapped is the value non optional and therefore assignable?

Comment: @JohnWoods, even if the optionals become mutable, that won't change the fact of being _optional_, and logically they cannot be at the _left_ side. however if the compiler is made smarter in future, it is possible on one day such operand won't be invalid, but for me seems clever (=faster) solution to chuck the chain away entirely if any of the elements is `nil` in the chain – thus I'm not expecting such update of the compiler, because a safe _runtime_ solution'd be _relatively_ much slower (with nested `if` statements).

Comment: very interesting, what you say makes perfect sense. I'm surprised Apple didn't explicitly mention you can't have optionals on the left hand side in their language guide!

Comment: seems to be fixed in Beta 5!

Comment: it's great, both assignment with ? and mutable value types... quite a change for the good! I think assignment with ? is great, we can effectively message nil like objc!

Answer (score 5):

Optional chaining works for reading values (return value or `nil`), it works for calling methods (call this method or do nothing) but doesn't work for assignments.

I believe this is by design but I don't see a reason why it is so because this is essentially the same as:

```
extension UIWindow {
    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor) {
        self.backgroundColor = color
    }
}

self.window?.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.redColor())
```

and that works without problems. You can report a bug or ask on the dev forums.
I believe optional chaining here is logically inconsistent.

Your example from dev forums doesn't have anything to do with this problem since that problem is about value types.

Comment: I don't think that a kind of bug... that is logical behaviour of the optional chaining to not grant to set any value for a possible `nil`.

Comment: @holex That's inconsistent with setter methods (not declared as properties). The behavior is technically the same. I see no reason why it should be forbidden.

Comment: in my logic that _must be_ forbidden, because the `nil = UIColor.greenColor()` is an invalid operand on every level, the optional value must not be on the _left_ side, but only on _right_.

Comment: your example is different because the optional is on the _right_ side, but because the return value is `void` and the _left_ side of the operand is not necessary.

Comment: Interesting points - so why is a forced unwrap ok in my example above?

Comment: @JohnWoods, because the forced-unwrapped value is not an optional at all, however your responsibility to set it a not-`nil` before you unwrap it – otherwise it crashes.

Comment: @holex I understand your distinction between left and right values, however, `nil.setBackgroundColor(...)` and `nil.backgroundColor = ...` is functionally the same, so there is no reason why this behavior should be disallowed. It is not inconsistent from implementation point of view but it's inconsistent from logical point of view.

Comment: in _ObjC_ that assumption would be correct, but in _Swift_ the second one (`nil.backgroundColor = ...`) is a simple `nil = ...` only, as the documentation refers that behaviour: _"(...) the entire chain fails gracefully if any link in the chain is `nil`."_

Comment: This is a good point, I also don't see why expressions like `foo?.bar[baz] = qux` can't be allowed. After quickly looking through Swift grammar it seems that should not be hard either.

Comment: @Sulthan seems to be fixed in Beta 5!