# Optional type behaviour with properties and methods

Tags: swift

Is it correct that properties for an optional element cannot be modified with Optional chaining?

```
class Something {
    var mark:Person?

    func changeAge{ 
        mark = Person()
        mark?.age = 40 <--- IT DOESN'T WORK.
        mark?.sayHello() <----- IT WORKS 
    }
}
```

Trying to perform a change on the `age` property I get this error: `Cannot assign to the result of this expression` but I can call the method `sayHello`. Since the two elements booth appertain to an instance of Person I can't understand why I can't access its properties but I'm allowed to access methods.

Edit: I know that I could use forced unwrap or optional binding... I'm just asking why I can't access properties that way but I can access methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift Optionals - Inconsistency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651402/swift-optionals-inconsistency)

Comment: I have answered the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651402/swift-optionals-inconsistency/24652296#24652296

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you *can't* access the method if it is nil - it's only called if `mark?` isn't nil. Assigning to the property is meaningless if `mark?` is nil, and if it isn't (and you're *sure* it isn't), you can assign to `mark!`. If you are *unsure* about whether it is nil, use:

```
if let m = mark {
   m.age = 40
}
```